# MAMP: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll'

Tags: php, mamp

I can't enable intl extension, I am getting this error:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' (tried: W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext\php_php_intl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Here are the files list in the directory:

```
    W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext>dir
     Volume in drive W is WEBSERVER
     Volume Serial Number is 2A6E-355C

     Directory of W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext

    Вт 31.12  11:20    <DIR>          .
    Вт 31.12  11:20    <DIR>          ..
    Чт 20.06  13:16            50 688 php_apcu.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16            70 656 php_bz2.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16           459 776 php_curl.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16            57 856 php_exif.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16         5 019 648 php_fileinfo.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16            42 496 php_ftp.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16         1 151 488 php_gd2.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16            49 152 php_gettext.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16           237 568 php_gmp.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16           221 696 php_imagick.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16           814 592 php_imap.dll
    Чт 20.06  13:16           327 168 php_intl.dll
```

W10
Apache/2.2.31 
MAMP 4.1.1

Why is that happening with this module? Others modules are being loaded without errors.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk yes that helped, strange listed a lot suggested topics and didn't fall to this answer. Many thanks.

Comment: You know that the first M in MAMP stands for 'Macintosh', right?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you added wrong .dll name in the php.ini load, it should be

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

instead of

```
extension=php_php_intl.dll.dll
```

Comment: I didn't add, just removed ; from extension=php_intl.dll and this line is present there. It seems like mamp or something else add one more .dll to the name maybe

Comment: what if you add it like extension=intl;

Comment: good idea btw, but seem solution is copy all icu files to apache bin.